# Used HDD/ran DiskSmartView/40,000 Power-on-hours?? should i trust it w/ my data, or take it back and complain?

Tags: hard-drive, lifespan, data-integrity

I just bought a used hard drive from a University Surplus Store.  Decided to run DiskSmartView to make sure it wasn't ready to fail.   **40,000 power-on-hours**
I don't know if I feel like trusting my data to something that used.  I really dont know if thats unreasonably old, but when i compare it to the POH reading i get when testing my other hdds its more than 3x older (my others have 2110 hours, 6150 hours, etc..
It's a Western Digital, so that gives me a little bit of hope(WDC WD4000KD-00NAB0).
I could sure use someone else's opinion here.
Thanks, DAVE

Comment: That's 4.5 years of continuous "up" time -- not a whole lot for a disk drive.

Comment: Seems like a long time..I guess my question is, "how long should I expect it to last, if it's already 4.5 yrs old?

Answer (score 0):

Per Google's study, hard drives either died very early or else lasted for quite awhile.  Dependent on the manufacturing date ?2005?, I'd suspect that the drive came out of a server or something so the drive may have lived constantly in a power-on condition.  The flip side is that it was possibly in a temperature and power conditioned environment.  Then again it may have been in a bit torrent server in someone's broom closet cooking away.  Make your decision also dependent on other parameters - things like temperature and redirected blocks.

Comment: I think so.  Youre dead on w/ the 2005.  Temp is cool.  There's an un-named column[132] with a raw value of 2,199,040,033,659.  Zero reallocated sectors though...